# How to edit pdf output in nbconvert

Tags: xetex, pdftex, miktex

I am trying to edit an output from nbconvert. I have a jupyter notebook which I wanted as a pdf. I used the following code to get the pdf output with miktext backend. `jupyter nbconvert --to pdf  Latex.ipynb --no-input` I want to edit the dates and numbers in the output. Latex o/p
[image]

Comment: Please do not cross-post, c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60341716/8416610

Comment: See how Jupyter does this. There must be a way to set date (and foirmat) and state chapter start/sectioning.